# Why am I getting NullPointerException in the CompilationUnit instances returned from ASTParser.createASTs()

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt, compilationunit

I am working on an Eclipse JDT plugin that requires parsing large numbers of source files,
so I am hoping to use the batch method ASTParser.createASTs(). The parsing executes without errors, but within the CompilationUnit instances it produces, many of the `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding` instances have had their `scope` field set to `null`. This setting to null is occurring in the `CompilationUnitDeclaration.cleanUp()` methods, which are invoked on a worker thread that is unrelated to my plugin's code (i.e., my plugin's classes do not appear on the `cleanUp()` method call stack).

My parsing code looks like this (all `rawSources` are within the same project):

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);

parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);
parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
parser.setIgnoreMethodBodies(false);
parser.setProject(project);
parser.createASTs(rawSources.values().toArray(new ICompilationUnit[0]), new String[0], this, deltaAnalyzer.progressMonitor);
```

Alternatively, I can execute the parsing this way, and no such problems occur:

```
for (ICompilationUnit source : rawSources.values())
{
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);
    parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
    parser.setIgnoreMethodBodies(false);
    parser.setProject(project);
    parser.setSource(source);
    CompilationUnit ast = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(deltaAnalyzer.progressMonitor);
    parsedSources.add(deltaAnalyzer.createParsedSource(source, ast));
}
```

This issue occurs in both Helios and Indigo (the very latest release build). I filed a bug in Eclipse Bugzilla, but if anyone knows of a way to work around this--or if I am using the API wrong--I would greatly appreciate your help.

Byron

Comment: What is the bugzilla issue that you raised?  Also, what is the stack trace that you have?

Comment: It's bug [#359478](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359478), which was marked a duplicate of [#189782](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=189782). Stack traces are in the bug, which is closed as duplicate, but the latter remains open. I'm working around it by simply parsing all ASTs for which I am using bindings, and using only IType et al. for library references. This is slow, but works fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what your exception is, I can still offer 2 suggestions:

1. Have a look at `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.SharedASTProvider`.  If you are not making any changes to ASTs, this class may provide a more robust way of getting the ASTs.
2. Play around with some of the settings that you are using.  Do you really need bindingsRecovery set to true?  What about statementRecovery?  Setting these to false may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that shared provider is good to know about, though my plugin analyzes every reference to the changed sources in the workspace, so I need to parse and retain all ASTs for the entire workspace. Binding and statement recovery are useful when a delta contains some sources with syntax errors that prevent analysis, and some sources with correct syntax that can be analyzed. What I'd really like is to plug directly into the compiler at a low level and contribute to each token evaluation, but that doesn't appear to be possible.